# Why has my employer's Word 2010 started insisting that there's an issue with my .doc files?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, docx, microsoft-word-2016

**When I asked my original question, I was advised to ask this part of it as a separate question.**

I regularly write reports for my employer, and email them through. I write the reports in Word 2016 for Mac, and my employer reads them in Word 2010 for Windows.

Recently, my employer has had the following banner appear whenever he opens one of my reports:

[image: Protected View]

I've done some testing on this, and it appears that this banner is displayed whenever my employer is opening a .doc file from me that I have created in Word 2016 for Mac. .docx files created in Word 2016 for Mac don't have this problem; neither .doc files or .docx files created in Word 2010 for Windows have this problem.

Any idea what the issue is here? It does seem that .doc files created in Word 2016 for Mac are around ten times bigger than .doc files created in Word 2010 for Windows, but I haven't been able to spot anything else that seems relevant.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are .doc files created by Word for Mac 2016 so big?](http://superuser.com/questions/1120402/why-are-doc-files-created-by-word-for-mac-2016-so-big)

Comment: Because the person who answered said "Protected view? maybe the file is corrupted, maybe you have a VBA macro embedded and they have a 100% lockdown on macro policy, who knows. I would ask that question separately", and since they have a higher reputation than me I thought I would do what they suggested.

Comment: The other question is about the size of the files.  This one is about an ominous error warning.  Different questions.  However, you might want to delete the image and sentence in the earlier question that adds this issue there.